# onRequestPermissionsResult not called in Flutter plugin when not using PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, flutter-plugin

I have a flutter plugin that is successfully asking for Android permissions through a bridge class, using

```
MyBridgeClass implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener, ActivityAware
```

and

```
binding.addRequestPermissionsResultListener(this);
```

This works fine and `onRequestPermissionsResult` is called.

However, I need my code usable for different bindings, not only Flutter, I need to support react-native, ionic/capacitator etc as well.

So, I tried to move my permission handling to a regular class inside my plugin code, using:

```
MyClass extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
```

but doing that, `onRequestPermissionsResult` is never called.

The code is the same in both places, requesting permissions with:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissionArray, 0);
```

and then waiting for the `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback.

Again, doing it in the Flutter bridge class is fine but I get no callback when using a regular Android class. I did exactly like in the [Google example](https://github.com/android/permissions-samples/blob/main/RuntimePermissionsBasic/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicpermissions/MainActivity.java) but I guess that this being a plugin/library might cause something to work differently?

I guess it is no big deal repeating the permission code in each bridge but it would be nice to not have to.

All ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I did find others with similar questions. Apparently, it does not work this way so I implemented an alternative solution where the processing and petition of the permission is in the library class but the callback is implemented in the bridge, just forwarding it to the library.